# How do you Save a ListView as a text document than loading it back into the program

Tags: java, listview

I am currently making a program where you can add and delete items from a listview in Java, i want it to be able to automatically save when you add items to the list view and delete items. I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this any help would be greatly appreciated. i am still very new at programming and still trying to figure it all out here is my code i have so far.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class LendingLibraryGUI extends Application {
    LendingLibrary LendingLibrary = new LendingLibrary(); //Creating an Object to access total numbers of items
    MediaItems Media = new MediaItems(); // creating an array of object to access MediaItems class and allowing it to hold 100 items 
    private ListView<String> library = new ListView<String>();
    ObservableList<String> libraryList = FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList("yes","no");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane display = new BorderPane(); //Main display
        GridPane buttons = new GridPane(); //location to display buttons
        TextField outPut = new TextField(); //Text field to show inventory
        Insets padding = new Insets(10); //creates Insets for padding
        buttons.setPadding(padding); //padding around grid pane
        buttons.setHgap(10); //Horizontal gap
        library.setItems(libraryList);



        for (int i =0; i !=4;i++) { //Loop to create Buttons
            String[] actionButtons = {"Add","Check Out","Check In","Delete"};//String to store Button names
            Button temp = new Button(actionButtons[i]);
            temp.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
            buttons.add(temp, i, 0); //add buttons to grid pane
            GridPane.setHgrow(temp, Priority.ALWAYS);
            GridPane.setVgrow(temp, Priority.ALWAYS);
            if (temp.getText().equals("Add")) {
                temp.setOnAction((e) -> add());
            }
            else if (temp.getText().equals("Delete")) {

                temp.setOnAction((e) -> deleteLibrary());

            }
        }


        outPut.setEditable(false); //no editing
        outPut.setFont(Font.font("monospace", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
        outPut.setMinHeight(300);//sets minimum height
        display.setTop(library); //sets output in display on top
        display.setCenter(buttons); //sets buttons on center 


        Scene scene = new Scene(display); //creates new scene
        primaryStage.setTitle("Lending Library"); //sets title of GUI
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); //adds scene to GUI
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(400); //Minimum height
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(350);//Minimum Width
        primaryStage.show();//Displays GUI to user
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }


    private void add() {
        inputGUI("Title:");
    }

    private void inputGUI(String input) {
        Stage secondaryStage = new Stage();
        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        VBox titlePane = new VBox(8);
        HBox buttonLayout = new HBox(8);
        Label lblTitle = new Label(input);
        Button save = new Button("Save");
        Button close = new Button("Close");
        Insets padding = new Insets(10);
        TextField txt = new TextField("");
        close.setOnAction((e) -> secondaryStage.close());;



        save.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                try {

                    LendingLibrary.save(library);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (txt.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {

                }
                else {

                    if (input.equals("Title:")) {
                        Media.setTitle(txt.getText());
                        secondaryStage.close();
                        inputGUI("Format:");
                    }
                    else if (input.equals("Format:")) {
                        Media.setFormat(txt.getText());
                        secondaryStage.close();
                        addToLibrary();
                    }
                    else if (input.equals("Who did you loan this to?")) {



                    }
                    else if (input.equals("When did you loan it(date)?")) {


                    }
                }

            }
        });

        buttonLayout.getChildren().addAll(close,save);
        titlePane.setPadding(padding);
        titlePane.getChildren().addAll(lblTitle,txt,buttonLayout);
        border.setCenter(titlePane);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(titlePane, Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(border); //creates new scene
        secondaryStage.setTitle("Input"); //sets title of GUI
        secondaryStage.setScene(scene); //adds scene to GUI
        secondaryStage.setMinHeight(200); //Minimum height
        secondaryStage.setMinWidth(350);//Minimum Width
        secondaryStage.show();//Displays GUI to user


    }


    private void addToLibrary() {
        String total;
        total = Media.getTitle();
        total = total + " ("+ Media.getFormat() +")";
        libraryList.add(total);
        library.setItems(libraryList);



    }

    private void deleteLibrary() {
        int selectedItem = library.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        libraryList.remove(selectedItem);
    }

    private void checkOut() {

    }

}
```

Any other pointers or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

edit:
Again im very new just trying to learn basic stuff this isnt something i am going to keep just going through a book and this is something in it that its trying to teach me.

```
public void save(ListView<String> library) throws IOException {
    File file = new File ("LendingLibrary.txt"); //creates text file
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);

    if(file.exists()) { //if the file exists
        output.println(library);
        output.close();

    }

    if(!file.exists()) { //if file doesn't exist
        System.out.println("Error creating file");
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really are interested to save is the data that is presented by the list view, you don't need all the other layout information and stuff as they are statically defined in the application and loaded on each run automatically.

Now, although saving the data in a file and loading it each time you need it can work, it is not usually the best. A better approach is to use a database to store the data of your application in form of relation entities, in this way you have a safer and a more consistent approach to work with. To get yourself started in the topic, you can go on and consult the official **[reference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite)**.

If you want to first try using the file approach, the advice is to save the data in some structured format which is then easy to save and load, or in more proper words serialize/deserialize. For this purpose you can use the `json` format to store the data in a file, and you can use [**gson**](https://github.com/google/gson) library for example:

1. Each row of the list view is an object that contains the data.
2. Reading: Serialize the list of data to `json` format using the `gson` and store each of them in a separate line.
3. Reading: Load the list of strings and deserialize them to the java class using `gson`.

Comment: im very new just trying to learn basic stuff this isnt something i am going to keep just going through a book and this is something in it that its trying to teach me, that is why im trying to do it through a text file and not learn how to do it in a database.

Comment: @SamuelDague I updated with some details for the file approach. Tell me if you need something more